# Jenkins plugin to re-try on different node?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Doesn't anyone know of a Jenkins plugin that ensures that when a job is re-run, it runs on a different node to the previous one? Problem is not all developers have permission to take problematic nodes offline, so they end up not being able to build their branch because Jenkins keeps trying to re-run on the same one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your nodes have same configuration; You can group them under same Label;

To re-run the build you can try - 
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Naginator+Plugin

You might want to configure node to get offline when idle for certain time.
And aim to re-trigger the build after that time; There is a fair chance the build would run on another Node.

But the question is, what are the chances of build getting successful if nothing has changed. Re-trigger without changes doesn't give successful build unless there is a temporary issue.

Comment: Not so much temporary as the fact our build relies on tools like docker and genymotion which randomly get themselves into non working states that require manually fixing. We don't want all Devs just marking builds offline willy nilly but for them to be able to retry a build on a different node would be hugely useful when nobody is around the fix the issue.